# Cant use prepare in ZF2 pdo database

Tags: sql, pdo, zend-framework2

In my controller:

```
    $this->db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');

    $statement = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM test');
    $result = $statement->execute();


    foreach($result as $r)
        var_dump($r);
```

I get a: *`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::prepare()`*

If I use `$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM test')` it works.

Why is *prepare* not present? Is it *query* an abstraction that checks the query for sql injection in ZF2?

Answer (score 1):

`Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` does not extend `PDO`, so it doesn't have to have `prepare` method. Instead, try to use `createStatement`. Just look at the source code [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Adapter.php);

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare a statment, so you should use the 'Sql' and 'Select' objects to do so.

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;

$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$select->from('test');

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $statement->execute();
```

This is in the ZF2 documentation. Here is [a link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html) to one of many pages that this example apears.